# Qt - ComboBox automatically in TableView?

Tags: c++, qt

So in my project, I had a TableView and i edited some of its info's in the Qt Editor itself. I also implemented all the codes for it and when I ran before, I could see a comboBox in a place of int. But for some reasons I had to replace that TableView with a new one. All the codes are the same, but I don't see any comboBox now. So does that mean the comboBox appeared for something done in the Editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you replaced your TableView in the qt designer and gave it the same name as before it shouldn't do anything to your c++ implementation of your class. The settings you enter in the qt designer will be deleted when you delete the TableView and you have to re-enter the ones you had before. So you can still use your previous c++ implementation of your class.

I usually design my gui in qt designer and then create a class that sets up signals/slots and initializes the widgets to my liking. So if you had setup your widgets from your class constructor you wouldn't have to worry about any of this.

Good luck!

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I didn't implement and widget from the class and i was surprised myself how the combobox appeared. Also, in the cell where i set the value to QDate::CurrentDate() the cell was automatically converted to a combobox for dates! How did that happen? o.O